# Upgrade grails within ggts

Tags: grails

Is there any way to upgrade project to newer version of Grails from within GGTS ?

Settings at 
Window > Preferences > Groovy > Grails 
changed settings only to newly created projects. Even if I set the newer version, if I run "grails upgrade" then it wants to upgrade to the older version.

I know, that I could do it from console, however messing with GRAILS_HOME on Windows is not the most pleasurable feeling in the world for me ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that GGTS don't download Grails versions. For Unix based systems you have the great [GVM tool](http://gvmtool.net/), and you can use it on Windows with [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

If this is not an option to you, there's the [Gravy](https://github.com/enterprise-grails/gravy), but be aware that:

> Gravy has no intention of competing with GVM and its rich
>   functionality set. Instead, it only addresses the task of switching
>   locally present Grails versions within the active command shell.

So it means that you have to manually download the Grails versions, and the bat will handle the switch from one to another.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I did not need to download other grails version - I already have it in my folder. What I wanted to do is to change grails version in GGTS for existing project, like you can change this setting for newly created project.

Comment: @konkit You have this option in the properties of the project.